# Как проверить, закрыт ли topic в супергруппе?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как проверять конкретный `topic` (у которого есть свой `message_thread_id`), закрыт он или нет, каждый раз? Или можно только отлавливать, когда его закрыли (`message.forum_topic_closed`)?